# Boostrap glyphicon inside input not showing on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

on my website, while hovering over the "Search" input or on focus, the glyphicon dissapears!

```
<div class="icon-addon addon-sm">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search (621 videos)" class="form-control" name="searchString" id="searchString">
                        <label for="searchString" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="search"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem here

```
.icon-addon .form-control:focus+.glyphicon, .icon-addon:hover .glyphicon, .icon-addon .form-control:focus+.fa, .icon-addon:hover .fa {
  color: #fff;
}
```

remove `.icon-addon:hover .glyphicon` from above css or remove `color` or set difference `color: #232323;` Your choice.